# Is "head data" a true alternative to "header data"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

Our software uses the term "head data" for which I think should be called "header data".

If I look up the German translation ["Kopfdaten" on Leo](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/kopfdaten), I only get "header data", not "head data".

For ["head data" on Oxford learners](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=head+data), I get no exact match, but neither for ["header data"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=header+data).

Linguee translates "Kopfdaten" to ["header data"](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=kopfdaten), but also links to DeepL, which offers the alternative ["head data"](https://www.deepl.com/translator/l/de/en?utm_source=lingueede&utm_medium=linguee&utm_content=examples&il=de#de/en/kopfdaten).

The Oxford learners dictionary [associates "header" with "footer"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/header?q=header)

> a line or block of text that appears at the top of every page in a book or document

, which IMHO is exactly what the software does.

But [definition 9 of "head"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/head_1?q=head) in Oxford learners

> [singular] head of something the top or highest part of something

does not sound totally wrong either.

Is "head data" a true synonym for "header data" or just a bad word-by-word translation of the German term "Kopfdaten"? Regarding usability and frequency of use, which one should the software use?

In the following picture, "head data" has an impact on the red part of the table which is at the beginning of the page.

[image: Beginning of a page containing "head data"]

Comment: Neither string, in my opinion, is likely to be familiar to the average educated Anglophone. I'd stick with the one that seems more common, but be ready to come across the variant (if such it is). Might be better asked on a computing site.

Comment: I agree it's better to ask on a computing site "what is this data called? is it called header data or head data?" There are a lot of questions asked here where people say "I know what the proper name for this is, but is it ok if I use another name anyway?" and it's always difficult to answer such questions. People would probably be able to work out "head data" from context, although if you sell hats or brain imaging, it might be confusing.

Comment: What is "Kopfdaten"? Is it the data returned by a [HEAD request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)? The code between [`<head>` tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp)? Or is it something that's actually shown on the page at the top, like a banner?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is specific to computing. It would be better on e.g. https://superuser.com/

Comment: metadata maybe?

Comment: @StuartF: I have attached an image for clarification

Comment: @Laurel: I have attached an image for clarification

Comment: @Esther: no, it's not data about data, but rather supplementary real data.

Comment: Except in some contrived circumstances, there is no such thing as "head data". "Header data" is commonly used.